# How to call constructors in main()?

Tags: c++, constructor, call, friend, istream

I'm working on a program that takes a `string` and a `int` as variables for my `friend` constructors.  I have most of my program done, but since I'm new to this topic of `friend`s and constructors with C++, I don't know how to implement the call on my `main()` to use these parameters and start working on my `istream` and `ostream` to ask the user to input
the values and start printing it.

Could someone please guide me the right way?

These are my current constructors:

```
jellyBeanFlavors::jellyBeanFlavors()
{
    flavor = "null";
    jellyBeans = 0;
}

jellyBeanFlavors::jellyBeanFlavors(int newJellyBeans)
{
    flavor = "null";
    jellyBeans = newJellyBeans;
}

jellyBeanFlavors::jellyBeanFlavors(string newFlavor, int newjellyBeans)
{
    flavor = newFlavor;
    jellyBeans = newjellyBeans;
}

void jellyBeanFlavors::output()
{
    cout << flavor << " " << jellyBeans << endl;
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement here my objects and start making my questions for input and then print with my `istream` function:

```
int main ()

    {
        jellyBeanFlavors::jellyBeanFlavors(string newFlavor, int newjellyBeans);

        jellyBeanFlavors();
        jellyBeanFlavors myFirstFlavor = jellyBeanFlavors.the;
        jellyBeanFlavors mySecondFlavor;
        jellyBeanFlavors total = 0;

        cout << "Your first flavor  is: "<< myFirstFlavor. << endl;
        cin >> myFirstFlavor;
        cout << "Your second flavor is: "<< mySecondFlavor << endl;
        cin >> mySecondFlavor;
        cout << "The expected result of adding" << " the first flavor loaded with" << mySecondFlavor <<" in the quantity with jellybean2 loaded with 6 in the quantity is: ";
        cout << "a jellybean with a quantity of 11.
        cout << "the result of adding jellybean1 and jellybean two is: " << jellybean1 + jellybean2 << endl;


        // this isnt implemented right but i need advice please on how to call my objects from my main class.


        system("pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

> so you dont get confused here is my main class:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class jellyBeanFlavors
    {
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator + (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean, jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);//sums
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator - (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean, jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);//(binary) substracts
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator - (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean);// (unary) checks negatives
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator * (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean,jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);//multiplies
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator / (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean,jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);//divides
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator == (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean,jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);//compares
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator < (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean,jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);// less than
        friend jellyBeanFlavors operator > (jellyBeanFlavors theFirstJellyBean,jellyBeanFlavors theSecondJellyBean);//greater than
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outputStream, const jellyBeanFlavors& jellyBeanOutput);// output
        friend istream& operator >> (istream& inputStream, jellyBeanFlavors& jellyBeanInput);//input 

    public:
        jellyBeanFlavors();
        jellyBeanFlavors(int);
        jellyBeanFlavors(string, int);
        void output();

    private:
        string flavor;
        int jellyBeans;

    };
```

> **> my solution to my program by adding objects and overloading
>   them:**
>
> my solution to my program by adding objects and overloading them:

```
 int main ()
    {   
        system("cls");
        char op;
        jellyBeanFlavors obj1,obj2,obj3;
        do{
            cin>>obj1;  //flavor
            cin>>obj2;  //amount 

            system("cls");
            cout<<"JELLYBEANS:"<<endl;

            obj3=obj1+obj2;
            cout<<"\n The Sum is : ";
            obj3.output();

            obj3=obj1-obj2;
            cout<<"\n The Substraction is : ";
            obj3.output();

            obj3=obj1*obj2;
            cout<<"\n The Multiplication is: ";
            obj3.output();

            obj3=obj1/obj2;
            cout<<"\n The Divide operation is : ";
            obj3.output();

            cout<<"\n"; 
            obj3 = obj1==obj2;
            obj3.output();
            cout<<"\n";

            obj3 = obj1>obj2;
            obj3.output();
            cout<<"\n";

            obj3 = obj1<obj2;
            obj3.output();
            cout<<"\n";

            obj3 = -obj1;
            obj3.output();
            cout<<"\n";

            obj3 = -obj2;
            obj3.output();
            cout<<"\n";

            cout<<"\n\nPress A/a and Enter to continue or 0 to exit"<<endl;
            cin>>op;
            if(op = 0)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }while(op =='a'|| op=='A');


        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Please read the first chapter of any c++ book. Your usage of objects is completely wrong.

Comment: Also there are several other errors.

Comment: this is not my complete code, im just showing my main constructors with the variables im initializing,and i jumped to my main(), just cutting the code.

Comment: I realize that however from your code it appears you do not even begin to understand c++ at all. There are way too many mistakes.

Comment: LihOs answer shows several ways of constructing objects in the stack. Similar code would work with your class.

Comment: Hint#2: Remove every line that you have: flavor = "null"; This is certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from many other syntax errors in the code you have provided, constructing objects with automatic storage duration should look like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { }          // <-- default constructor
    A(int i) { }     // <-- constructor taking int

    void foo() { }   // <-- member function ("method")
    static s() { }   // <-- static function
};
```

and somewhere:

```
A a;           // <-- constructs object using the default constructor
A a2 = A();    // <-- equivalent to the previous one (copy initialization)
A a3(a2);      // <-- copy constructor ~ constructs a3 using the a2 object
A a4(7);       // <-- constructs object using the constructor taking int

// now when you have some objects, you can call member functions
// (i.e. invoke the behavior they provide)
a.foo();

// static functions are not dependent on objects:
A::s();        // <-- calls static function defined within namespace of class A
```

Before you continue in writing more codes, consider spending some time reading some decent book.
In case you're not sure about what book to read, here you might find one: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1168156)

Comment: actually im reading: Absolute C++ (5th Edition) course book.

Comment: Concentrate on whatever chapter teaches about classes.

Comment: im kinda there i just havent solved how to get my main() implemented yet,but thank you for everyone giving each hint.

Comment: @yamicaitsith: "im kinda there" sounds like you skipped chapters that actually shouldn't be skipped. Also start with simpler stuff before you start overloading operators etc. Also note that `using namespace std;` isn't a good way how to start a header file.

Comment: the fact is that in my course with our instructor we are not applying header files and we already went through classes and structs, im not quite understanding the implementation of the usage of friends in a class and how to call that by reference in my main().

Comment: maybe my questions are not the right ones to be asking and im confusing what im asking for.

Comment: I would not worry about friends and operator overloading at this point when you do not understand simple objects.

Comment: maybe your right but this is part of my assignment, but ill keep trying and get my solution by backtracking my implementation in my code.

Comment: ok... after reading classes over and over i got my program to work out by just making objects to and start doing things with the and get the solution to my problem. sorry im posting this late but ill leave this code example for anyone who might need it as i did once: